# Spring Boot Oauth client does not work on Google App Engine

Tags: spring, spring-boot, google-app-engine, kotlin, oauth-2.0

I have the minimal working example of `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client`

1. pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

2. SecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
class SecurityConfig : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login()
    }

    override fun configure(web: WebSecurity?) {
        web?.ignoring()?.mvcMatchers("/actuator/health")
    }
}
```

3. UserController

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
class UserController {
    @GetMapping
    fun user(principal: Principal) : Principal {
        return principal
    }
}
```

4. application.properties

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-id=<client id>
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-secret=<client secret>
```

5. Google Cloud Platform configuration

`APIs & Services -> Credentials -> Oauth consent screen -> Authorized domains` - has the dmain on my application (`<service>-dot-<project>.appspot.com`)

`APIs & Services -> Credentials -> OAuth 2.0 client IDs` - I have a Client id with:

`Authorized redirect URIs`

- `http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/google`
- `http://<service>-dot-<project>.appspot.com/login/oauth2/code/google`

  6. App Engine config

app.yaml

```
runtime: custom
env: flex
service: <my-service-name>
readiness_check:
  path: "/actuator/health"
  check_interval_sec: 5
  timeout_sec: 4
  failure_threshold: 4
  success_threshold: 2
  app_start_timeout_sec: 300
liveness_check:
  path: "/actuator/health"
  check_interval_sec: 30
  timeout_sec: 4
  failure_threshold: 2
  success_threshold: 2
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 2
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

and a Dockerfile

```
FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/openjdk:8
COPY target/oauth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar $APP_DESTINATION
```

When I run the application on `localhost` everything works! No drama! I'm prompted to login with my google email and password and can access the /user endpoint.
But when I try to deploy the same app on the Google App Engine and access the /user endpoint the behavior is inconsistent:
Sometimes I get the Spring Security generated login page with error:

`authorization_request_not_found` or `Invalid Credentials` (After I click the Google button to login)

[image: Auth Request Not Found]

[image: Invalid Credentials]

What could be the reason for the different behavior?

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be in the multiple instances created by the App Engine and the fact that my application does not work properly with multiple instances. With the current setup the login information is stored in the session of the server, so with multiple instances the load-balancer can send you to an instance that does not have an active session.

I've added:

```
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
```

to the `app.yaml` and it works OK.

Obviously the proper fix is to make the application stateless. Update on this is pending...